# Resolve the debugs

Tags: menus, apache

I enable the debugs, and i have these that describe below.
In the `wp-config.php` write :

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG', false);
```

1)

> Notice: Undefined index: type in C:\xampp\htdocs\mywebsite\wp-content\plugins\oqey-gallery\gallcore.php on line 252

*on line 252 :*

```
//media_upload_header();
    if($_GET['type'] == "oqeygallery"){ include ("insert_in_post.php"); }
```

> 2) Notice: add_custom_background is deprecated since version 3.4! Use add_theme_support( 'custom-background', $args ) instead. in C:\xampp\htdocs\mywebsite\wp-includes\functions.php on line 2638
>
> 3) Notice: attribute_escape is deprecated since version 2.8! Use esc_attr() instead. in C:\xampp\htdocs\mywebsite\wp-includes\functions.php on line 2638
>
> 4)Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\mywebsite\wp-content\themes\mywebsite\includes\for_articles\get_excerpt.php on line 12

```
function get_excerpt()
    {
        $excerpt = get_the_content();
        $excerpt = preg_replace(" (\[.*?\])",'',$excerpt);
        $excerpt = strip_shortcodes($excerpt);
        $excerpt = strip_tags($excerpt);
        $excerpt = substr($excerpt, 0, 440);
        $excerpt = substr($excerpt, 0, strripos($excerpt, " "));
        $excerpt = trim(preg_replace( '/\s+/', ' ', $excerpt));
        $excerpt = $excerpt.'<a class="read-more" <a href="'. get_permalink($post->ID) . '">Read more &raquo;&raquo;</a>';
        return $excerpt;
    }
?>
```

Edit:

Notice: attribute_escape is deprecated since version 2.8! Use esc_attr() instead. in /home/www/server/mywebsite/www/wp-includes/functions.php on line 2638

```
function _deprecated_function( $function, $version, $replacement = null ) {

    do_action( 'deprecated_function_run', $function, $replacement, $version );

    // Allow plugin to filter the output error trigger
    if ( WP_DEBUG && apply_filters( 'deprecated_function_trigger_error', true ) ) {
            if ( ! is_null($replacement) )
**2638**                trigger_error( sprintf( __('%1$s is <strong>deprecated</strong> since version %2$s! Use %3$s instead.'), $function, $version, $replacement ) );
            else
                trigger_error( sprintf( __('%1$s is <strong>deprecated</strong> since version %2$s with no alternative available.'), $function, $version ) );

        }
    }
```

**Update :** 
Only when activate the plugin oQey Gallery, display some errors like:

```
Notice: Undefined index: type in C:\xampp\htdocs\website\wp-content\plugins\oqey-gallery\gallcore.php on line 252
Notice: Undefined index: page in C:\xampp\htdocs\website\wp-content\plugins\oqey-gallery\oqeygallery.php on line 346
Notice: has_cap was called with an argument that is deprecated since version 2.0! Usage of user levels by plugins and themes is deprecated. Use roles and capabilities instead. in C:\xampp\htdocs\website\wp-includes\functions.php on line 2723
```

Comment: I don't see anything that should make Apache crash. I'd suggest you debug your server itself.

Comment: @ s_ha_dum. Sorry, but need somewhere to start to get in trouble. First, i want to learn if i can solve these, and finally if I fail to solve these, if there is a problem. I edit the title and the content. Now, it is right?

Comment: These are four unrelated PHP notices. In the future, please use a separate question for each separate issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Number 1 is not wordPress, but PHP. `$_GET['type']` is undefined. Use an `isset( $_GET['type'] )` conditional.

Number 2 the error message tells you exactly what to do. Instead of calling:

```
add_custom_background();
```

...call:

```
add_theme_support( 'custom-background' );
```

Number 3 the error message tells you exactly what to do. Instead of calling:

```
attribute_escape();
```

...call:

```
esc_attr();
```

Number 4 is telling you that you're trying to get the property of an object that isn't set. In this yes, that object is `$post`, which needs to be *globalized* before you use it. Instead of this:

```
$excerpt = $excerpt.'<a class="read-more" <a href="'. get_permalink($post->ID) . '">Read more &raquo;&raquo;</a>';
```

...do this:

```
global $post;
$excerpt = $excerpt.'<a class="read-more" <a href="'. get_permalink($post->ID) . '">Read more &raquo;&raquo;</a>';
```

Comment: thanks for the help. In which line i call the `esc_attr();` `// Allow plugin to filter the output error trigger
 if ( WP_DEBUG && apply_filters( 'deprecated_function_trigger_error', true ) ) {
  if ( ! is_null($replacement) )
   trigger_error( sprintf( __('%1$s is <strong>deprecated</strong> since version %2$s! Use %3$s instead.'), $function, $version, $replacement ) );
  else
   trigger_error( sprintf( __('%1$s is <strong>deprecated</strong> since version %2$s with no alternative available.'), $function, $version ) );
 }
}` Thanks

Comment: You call `esc_attr()` on whatever line you currently call `attribute_escape()`. You replace `attribute_escape( $foobar )` with `esc_attr( $foobar )`, where `$foobar` is the string being escaped.

Comment: Bennet. In the first error, If I replace that you suggest me, makes wrong/error again.

Comment: Can you update your **original question** with the **new code** you used, and the **error message** you observed?

Comment: Ok, @Chip Bennett i updated!

Comment: In your update, I don't see anything about `add_theme_support( 'custom-background' )`?

Comment: Bennet, sorry. Updated form scratch.

Comment: I rolled back that edit. You basically deleted your question and replaced it with an entirely new question. Please don't do that. Please post a new question, if you have a new issue.

Comment: ok. Sorry about that.